# What is the profileId in Node Discovery Response from XBee?

Tags: xbee

I am learning about XBee and looking at Node Discover (ND) command. The response has profileId but i can't find explanation about that field. Can you point me to XBee doc that explains what that field is for? Can you use that field to replace response from Device Type Identifier (DD) command?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The ND command already has a response of  the device type.

About the profile id, take a look at page on 35 of [XBee ZB User Manual](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/XBee%20ZB%20User%20Manual.pdf), "ZigBee Application Layers: In Depth":

"Application profiles can be defined as "Public" or "Private" profiles. Private profiles are defined by a manufacturer whereas public profiles are defined, developed, and maintained by the ZigBee Alliance. Each application profile has a unique profile identifier assigned by the ZigBee Alliance.

Examples of public profiles include:

- Home Automation
- Smart Energy
- Commercial Building Automation"

So, if you are using only XBees on your network, you don't need to care about the profile id. You should care, only if you need to talk to another "kind of network" (profile), like "Smart Energy", etc.